# How to download all songs from an Amazon cloud drive

Tags: cloud, amazon

How can I download all songs from my Amazon Cloud Drive?

The web interface doesn't provide a *Select All* feature, and there isn't an Amazon Cloud API like the S3 API. There is the [Amazon MP3 Downloader](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_200143320_download_comp?nodeId=200593990), but that only downloads songs that you select from the web interface.

I've been thinking about using a mouse-clicking script (Automator or [Python](http://www.geekorgy.com/index.php/2010/06/python-mouse-click-and-move-mouse-in-apple-mac-osx-snow-leopard-10-6-x/) on OSX), but just wanted to check if anyone else determined a solution before I get to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest method was to use [Gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/) to mount my Amazon Cloud Drive in Windows, which allowed me to *Ctrl-A* and drag-and-drop from File Explorer. The starter edition (free) of Gladinet limits you to "1000 items per task" (I think that means copying 1000 items at a time).

Comment: This accepted answer is outdated in 2019

Answer (score 6):

You can install [Amazon Cloud Player for PC](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1001067901) and download your songs from it.

Comment: This worked for me. Once you've downloaded your music, it can be found in (on Win7): `C:\Users\<yourusername>\My Music\Amazon MP3`.

Comment: Interesting. This wasn't possible in 2011.

Comment: This works on Mac OS, too. Your music is in `~/Music/Amazon MP3`. iTunes should then automatically index it.

Answer (score 3):

While this is a bit of a dated question, Amazon now has a Cloud Drive App that allows you to select your entire music folder from the Cloud Drive (NOT the Cloud Player) view. You access it similarly to the Cloud PLayer - from the drop down menu at the upper right of the amazon.com page. I haven't seen this functionality advertised anywhere, but it works pretty well. Be patient while it sets things up!

Comment: You can't download more than one item at a time however.

Comment: No - you can select the "Archived Music" folder from the amazon cloud drive web site (which you can get to from the cloud drive app). Then, you click the download button. Did you try this? I've actually use this once already.

Comment: For me it says "Cloud Drive does not support downloading more than one file at a time. Please select a single file to download. Downloading Music? Launch Cloud Player" However in cloud drive it says you can't download more than one song if you're on linux. I guess I can switch to a windows/osx machine to do that.

Comment: Just to confirm, I've only had this work on OS X. Seems odd they wouldn't support linux the same way... it's an adobe air application after all.

Comment: 2015 update: Windows 7: Search amazon for Amazon Cloud Drive Desktop - it is a $0.00 purchase. When you launch the app there is an area at the top you can click that says "Download your Cloud Drive" that will get all your music (and photos, everything on amazon cloud drive) in a single click.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like you're stuck with the Amazon MP3 Downloader. Currently it only supports the downloading of 500 songs at a time and there is no direct Amazon API, so your best bet is probably to create a script. Hope your script works out!

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything to download my 4000 songs, and this is the only method that worked:

1. Open Amazon Music application
2. Change preferences to use one download thread
3. Choose Cloud view
4. Choose Artists view
5. Select one artist square
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
7. Right-click and choose Download

After it completed, I had one song unable to download. I just had to redownload that one song.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [JSShell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsshell/kmgmkbicahmbceidoidjbkbpkfogaldh?hl=en) extension to run some checkbox-clicking javascript>

```
$("[type='checkbox'][itemtype='song']")
  .each(function(idx, elem)
  {
    if (!elem.checked)
      elem.click();
  });
```

I needed to scroll down manually, and run it a few times, in order to get all the checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to select everything in the Cloud MP3 app by just using Ctrl-A  Then dragging everything over to the "download" space.

Of course this just dumps it in the default windows "Music" folder, but I can move it from there.

Answer (score 0):

To download all music via Amazon Music Player:

1. Open Amazon Music Player
2. Click 'Your Library'
3. Click the cloud icon on the left
4. Click "Songs"
5. Press CTRL+A
6. Right click on the selected list
7. Click "Download"

A side note you can also set the maximum number of simultaneous downloads in the settings. For large libraries being restored over large down stream connections, setting this to the max (6) is preferable.

1. Open Amazon Music Player
2. Click the hamburger icon on the top left
3. Choose Preferences
4. Click 'advanced' at the top
5. Change "Simultaneous Downloads" to whatever makes sense

The settings also let you choose an alternate location to download to. To see where this is and/or change it:

1. Open Amazon Music Player
2. Click the hamburger icon on the top left
3. Choose Preferences, you should be on the 'general' tab
4. Under "Manage downloads:"  there is a folder path next to "All downlaods are stored here: "
5. If you want to change it click "change..." and select a new destination

Answer (score 0):

In the distant future (year 2020), using Firefox, selecting the song at the top of the list, scrolling down, and then SHIFT-click on the checkbox to select the song at the bottom of the list selects all, up to a maximum of 500 at a time. However, you can only actually download less than that (I did 200 at a time)--it will look like it works, but then you receive a blank dialog and no download.

I recommend working in a playlist so the songs are numbered and you can easily select 200 at a time.